# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'external_stylesheets'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to make my first Dash application and I'm having one or several issue(s).

Here is my full code (don't pay attention to French comments). That's not a developped code, I'm just trying to discover Dash:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

### Importation des librairies

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc # Graphs
import dash_html_components as html # Tags
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, Event
from pandas_datareader import DataReader
import time
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
import random
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import statistics
from datetime import *
from pytz import *

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets) # Starting application

app.layout = html.Div(children=[ # HTML of the entire project
    html.H1(children='Générez votre fichier de données !'), # H1 = Titre 1 en HTML, premier "enfant"

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''), # Deuxième enfant

    html.Div([
    html.Div(
            dcc.Checklist(
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Inlet 1 ST1', 'value': 'I1ST1'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 2 ST1', 'value': 'I2ST1'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 3 ST1', 'value': 'I3ST1'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 4 ST1', 'value': 'I4ST1'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 5 ST1', 'value': 'I5ST1'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 6 ST1', 'value': 'I6ST1'},
                        ],
                labelStyle = {'display': 'block'}
                        )
            ),

    html.Div(
            dcc.Checklist(
                     options=[
                    {'label': 'Inlet 1 ST2', 'value': 'I1ST2'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 2 ST2', 'value': 'I2ST2'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 3 ST2', 'value': 'I3ST2'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 4 ST2', 'value': 'I4ST2'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 5 ST2', 'value': 'I5ST2'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 6 ST2', 'value': 'I6ST2'},
                        ],
                labelStyle = {'display': 'block'}
                        )
            ),

    html.Div(
            dcc.Checklist(
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Inlet 1 MT', 'value': 'I1MT'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 2 MT', 'value': 'I2MT'},
                    {'label': 'Inlet 3 MT', 'value': 'I3MT'}
                        ],
                labelStyle = {'display': 'block'}
                        )
            )]
            )

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True) # Running the application
```

I was just modifying pieces of code and refreshing the app, until I could not launch it anymore. First, I could launch the app on Spyder but got that message on my browser (chrome) :

```py
Error loading layout
```

1 hour later, the error had changed. This time I got it in Spyder:

```py
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'external_stylesheets'
```

So I tryed to remove the part of the code with "external_sheetsheets" then I got that message on my browser (with a big traceback):

```py
builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'config'

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

I didn't remember having modified any code before it has stopped working, but in case I did, I tryed to launch the example Dash app (With SF and Montréal) but it did the same!

Then I tryed to launch my code on another computer, and I got "Error loading layout" again. I also tryed to launch the Dash example on it, **and it worked well!**

So I just tryed another time to launch my code and the example app on the first computer. But for both of them I again got:

```py
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'external_stylesheets'
```

Being a poor non-English-speaker beginner, I couldn't find out the issue. Is my code working on your computer? Where does the problem come from? What can I do to fix everything?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It was not working for me until I updated to the latest version of Dash, `dash==1.0.0`. Now it works perfectly just as you posted it.

Comment: I uninstall then reinstall all dash components, and it worked. Everything's fine!